# dynamic images within slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div class 'container' and 'inner', inner show/hide a single image that slides up from the bottom of the div.  The issue comes when I try to have the 'inner' div display an image from an if statement rather than the image identified in the css.  Can someone please show me where my code is wrong.

```
<style>
body {margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;}
.swipe {overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; position: relative;}
.swipe-wrap {overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
.swipe-wrap > div {float:left; width:100%; position: relative;}
#mySwipe div b {display:block; margin:0px; margin-top:240px; background:url(""); height:1280px; width:720px;}

.container {bottom:106px ;display:none ;position:absolute;}
.inner {background_image:url(); height:440px; width:800px;}

.brand1{background-image:url(apple_name.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:360px; width:360px;} 
.brand2{background-image:url(windows_name.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:360px; width:360px;} 
.brand3{background-image:url(android_name.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:360px; width:360px;} 
</style>


<script>
        function change(v) {
    var target = document.getElementById("mySwipe");

         if (v == "imgA") {target.className = "brand1";}
    else if (v == "imgB") {target.className = "brand2";}
    else if (v == "imgC") {target.className = "brand3";}
    else {target.className = "inner";}
}

function changeReset() {
    var target = document.getElementById("container");
    target.className = "inner";
}
</script>

<div id='mySwipe' style='width:720px; height:981px; margin-top:55px;' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div><a id="imgB" href="#"><img src="apple.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div><a id="imgB" href="#"><img src="windows.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div><a id="imgC" href="#"><img src="android.jpg" /></a></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

// pure JS
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {

});

</script>

<div class='container'>
<div class='inner'>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubfmT/

Comment: A fiddle from http://jsfiddle.net will help clarify your problem more and more likely get someone to help you.

Comment: @JofryHS Here is a fiddle link.  Note the swipe mechanic is not working on desktops, but is working on android and other mobiles.  Again, I am trying to make the change() work so when the image swipes, the proper target appears when called.  http://jsfiddle.net/ubfmT/